# Best practices for Razor view-specific JQuery code in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've read a bit about including js libraries and using `RenderSection` to dynamically and optionally load extra libraries on demand.

To date, I've seen most view-specific scripts included directly inside `script` tags inside the view files themselves.  Is there a different/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to place all your JS files in a section att the end of your "_Layout.cshtml".

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

But notice that all your JS files will be fint at all your pages then. If you want som JS files in only one our a few of your pages, you can add a new section for this JS files. And set this section required attribute to false.

Comment: Right -- K. Scott Allen has a great video on this on the ASP.NET site.  I was wondering about the view-specific portion of the scripts, not the location of the script includes.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to make sure that you're only including scripts that are relevant for that particular page.

So including jQuery in the _Layout page is a good idea if you're using it on every page but you may only need jQuery validate on a page that actually has inputs to validate. Otherwise you're just downloading an extra file you don't need. Always remember that any unnecessary HTTP requests can be costly.

The use of `RenderSection` here is appropriate, even if it is just to organize it.

Comment: I understood the part on the includes, but my question was regarding the "wiring-up" portion of the scripts, not the js includes.